# Is there a way to delay the rendering of angular Material Spinner?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, css-animations, spinner

Simple question I can't seem to discern from the docs.  Can you delay a mat-spinner animation from rendering?

I have a 'mat-spinner>' rendering while my service gets data from an observable but when I switch between tabs the spinner pops up for like half a second.  I know I could build in another if statement to stop it from rendering all together after the data has been fetched but I'd like to do this via css if possible.  Is there any way to delay this animation built into material design?

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="!messageReady">
          <mat-spinner class="loading"></mat-spinner>
        </ng-container>
```

I could wrap it with another conditional but wondering if it can be done in the animations.

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you are evaluating "show spinner when fetching data", when what you actually want is "show spinner only on the first tab when fetching data". So instead you should consider all condition of interest. Maybe you could do something like `switchTabs() { this.messageReady = true;  doTheSwitch(); }` and force the spinner to go away because the conditions for it to be displayed are no longer met.

Comment: 100% Keenan.  I was just curious if Material design had some parameters built in that could solve it from a CSS perspective.

Comment: Yeah not seeing anything like that in the docs (https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/api#MatSpinner). Of course you could always do something like `[class.invisible]="!messageReady"`, where your css would be `.invisible {display: none}` or `.invisible {visibility: hidden}`